# Ruby squeeze alternative in go

Tags: ruby, string, go

Ruby strings had a method called `squeeze`. From ruby docs :

> Builds a set of characters from the other_str parameter(s) using the
>   procedure described for String#count. Returns a new string where runs
>   of the same character that occur in this set are replaced by a single
>   character. If no arguments are given, all runs of identical characters
>   are replaced by a single character.

```
"yellow moon".squeeze                  #=> "yelow mon"
"  now   is  the".squeeze(" ")         #=> " now is the"
"putters shoot balls".squeeze("m-z")   #=> "puters shot balls"
```

IS there an alternative function for this operation in golang? If not whats the best way to do it in go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
func Squeeze(s string) string {
    result := make([]rune, 0)
    var previous rune
    for _, rune := range s {
        if rune != previous {
            result = append(result, rune)
        }
        previous = rune
    }
    return string(result)
}
```

Bear in mind that strings are UTF8 in Go so you have to use runes (characters) rather than bytes in order to be compatible with non-ASCII strings.

Comment: That is awesome that Go calls them "runes" :-)